# Popen Executes At the Wrong Time

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I am writing a python script and when I run the code, all the code after I run subprocess gets executed before subprocess itself. So for example here the program will run print("blahblafkenrferkfnrnkr") before subprocess.

How do I make it so the program runs `print("blahblafkenrferkfnrnkr")` after `subprocess.Popen("timeout 60 python2 script.py", shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")` has executed `(for 60 seconds as I am trying to do)`

```
print("blahblh")

subprocess.Popen("timeout 60 python2 script.py", shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")

print("blahblafkenrferkfnrnkr")
```

Answer (score 0):

`Popen` launches a process to execute in the background, and you're not waiting for it to complete. Either:

1. Use one of the high-level wrappers for `Popen` that waits for you (e.g. `subprocess.run` by default, or one of the `subprocess.check*` family)
2. Store the resulting process object and call `wait` on it (`communicate` also works, but since you're not sending/capturing input/output, it's unnecessary)

Example for #2 would just be:

```
print("blahblh")

proc = subprocess.Popen("timeout 60 python2 script.py", shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
proc.wait()

print("blahblafkenrferkfnrnkr")
```